# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
require_once 'connect_db.php'; // подключаем скрипт
// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
or die("Ошибка" . mysqli_error($link));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'tittle' FROM 'news'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['tittle'];
// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Забудьте о функциях `mysql_`! Их нет в современном PHP уже.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() - читайте что вам выдает PHP! Он говорит что такой функции как вы вызываете не существует! Напишите так `$result = mysqli_query("SELECT 'tittle' FROM 'news'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, не используйте функции `mysql` - они ещё года 2 назад были устаревшими, а щас тем более. 
Во-вторых, используйте `mysqli_query(строка подключения, запрос)`
В вашем случае:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 'tittle' FROM 'news'")
```